# F# and ADO.NET to Connect To Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ado.net, f#

I am very new to F#, and I was trying to find the simplest way to connect to Access 2007 using System.Data.OleDb.  I have done this with C#, but I cannot figure out how to convert the syntax to F#.  The following is what I know so far:

```
#light
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Data.OleDb
open System.Data

let ADOCon = new OleDbConnection()
let DTab = new DataTable()

ADOCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\...mdb"
```

I know the syntax for the connection string is wrong, and I cannot figure out how to add an OleDataAdapter and OleCommandBuilder.  Does anyone know a straight forward example starting from #light to open connection? Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is so NOT the F# way to do things, but this works ...

```
open System.Data  
open System.Data.OleDb

let cmd = new OleDbCommand( "SELECT * FROM TABLE1" );
let conn = new OleDbConnection( @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\Database1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;" )

conn.Open();
cmd.Connection <- conn;
  using (cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    (fun reader ->
      if (reader.HasRows) then
        (
          printfn "Queried: %s" cmd.CommandText
          while (reader.Read()) do
            (
              let id = reader.GetInt32(0)
              let tmp = reader.GetString(1)

              printfn "%d %s" id tmp
            )
          done
        )
      else (printfn "Empty result")
      )

conn.Close();
;;
```

Comment: Thanks - the two lines of code directly below open System.Data.OleDb helped me immensely.  Now I am having problems filling my datatable.  I am actually using a winform and associated controls to display the data from the Access database, so I am using a DataAdapter and DataTable.  For example, DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) is not working; although, probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you show the corresponding C# it may help.

Assuming you are trying to assign a property on the last line, then you want "<-":

```
ADOCon.ConnectionString <- "yadda"
```

Comment: Thanks - so far I have worked out the following; however, I cannot seem to fill my datatable:

let frmMain = new Form()
//Connect to Accesss Db//
let ADOCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\...\Desktop\FSharpDb.mdb")
let DAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Names_Table", ADOCon)
let DTable = new DataTable()
DAdapter.Fill(DTable)

let ConnectionString = 
    ADOCon.Open()

Answer (score 0):

I finally compiled some code to to read an Access 2007 Db in F# from a winform:

```
open System.Data.OleDb
open System.Data

//Create winform//
let frmMain = new Form()

//Connect to Access Db//
let ADOCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
  Data Source=C:\Users\...\Desktop\FSharpDb.mdb")

let DAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Names_Table", ADOCon)

let DTable = new DataTable()
DAdapter.Fill(DTable)|>ignore
let view = new DataGridView()
do view.DataSource <- DTable

let ConnectionString = 
    ADOCon.Open()

frmMain.Controls.Add(view)

//Run main form on start up
Application.Run(frmMain)
```

Thank you for all who helped!